# CSS transition for a faux crop on an image

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm working on a header with a logo placed above a navbar. When a user begins to scroll down the page, the header shrinks with a CSS transition and the logo is "cropped" and it's position is moved to fit within the reduced header. This works really well. However, I'm trying to find a way to also animate the "crop" on the logo. What I'm currently getting is the re-positioning of the logo animated.

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3ehg1hLf/

Is it possible to put a transition on the logo class that would animate it's reduction, rather than it's position?

My HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="container-fluid no-pad">
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="row xyz">

        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <span class="logo"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/5MchhVA.png?1" /></span>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;  
}

.no-pad {
    padding: 0;
}


.xyz {
    max-width: 1280px;
    height: 91px;
    background: blue;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    /* For Scroll Transition */
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all .4s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all .4s ease-out;
    transition: all .4s ease-out;
}

.col-xs-4 {
  padding-top: 3px;
}

.cropxyz {
            height: 50px;
        }

    .logo {
            width: 100%;
        }

        .crop360 {
            display: inline-block;
            width:129px;
            height:36px;
            overflow:hidden;
            margin-top: 8px;
            /* For Scroll Transition*/
            -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in;
            -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in;
            -o-transition: all .4s ease-in;
            transition: all .4s ease-in; 
        }

        .crop360 img {
            position:relative;
            /*width: 100%;*/
            top: 40%;
            transform: translateY(-50%);

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did this by:

- using the logo element with a `background-image` instead of an img element
- In the 'smaller' mode, lower the `height` of the element
- `background-position:center` ensures it's the top and the bottom that is cropped

example:
https://jsfiddle.net/scnfbzek/